Derivation total demand using Roy's identity
I have a "resource-balance" equation of the form (imports in sector $i$) = (number of $i$ demanded domestically) - (number of good $i$ supplied domestically). I can't figure out how the total demand (second term) is derived.
The equation is as follows:

where $I^h$ is the income of each agent (determined by more than just wages), who are indexed by $h$.
A note states: "We have used Hotelling's lemma and Roy's identity (which are the derivative properties of the profit and indirect utility functions) to state labor demand and commodity supplies and demands in terms of these functions."
I can recognize that $-\frac{\partial V(p)}{\partial p_i}$ is the numerator of Roy. Intuitively, I would start off with $\sum_h x_i(p,I^h) =\sum_h \frac{\frac{\partial V}{\partial p_i}}{\frac{\partial V}{\partial I^h}}$, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Do we even use $w$ or $I^h$?

This is the full context:


When the utility function is homothetic, the indirect utility function becomes $v(p,I^h)=V(P)I^h$ and your expression for Roy's identity simplfies to $\frac{\partial V(p)}{ \partial p_i} \frac{I^h}{V(p)}. $
